# Unrecognized soap action

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am not familiar with SOAP webservices and I need to send a request to one.
I wrote the next snippet:

```
# WSDL http://webservices.sathomologa.sef.sc.gov.br/wsDfeSiv/Recepcao.asmx?WSDL
$this->client = new SoapClient(static::SERVICE_WSDL, ['exceptions' => 0]);

# Raw XML data
$data = $this->xml->saveXML();
# URL http://webservices.sathomologa.sef.sc.gov.br/wsDfeSiv/Recepcao.asmx
$location = static:SERVICE_URL;
$action = static::SERVICE_URL . '?op=Enviar';
$v = SOAP_1_1;

$response = $this->client->__doRequest($data, $location, $action, $v);
```

And I get the next test response:

> soap:ClientServer did not recognize the value of HTTP Header
>   SOAPAction:
>   http://webservices.sathomologa.sef.sc.gov.br/wsDfeSiv/Recepcao.asmx?op=Enviar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [specification](http://webservices.sathomologa.sef.sc.gov.br/wsDfeSiv/Recepcao.asmx?op=Enviar) of Enviar method, i saw the next header:

> SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/Enviar"

So, i changed `$action = static::SERVICE_URL . '?op=Enviar';` to `$action = http://tempuri.org/Enviar;` and works for me.